# WriteFile error and file pointer reposition

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm using `WriteFile` to write x bytes in a file.

If it **fails** (because of bad sectors or anything else...),
where will be the file pointer ?

1. where it was before the last write
2. where it was before the last write + x bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file pointer will be wherever the last written byte is located.  So if you ask `WriteFile()` to write X bytes and it was able to successfully write Y bytes before the failure occured, then the file pointer will be located at +Y bytes from where the file pointer started at.